# Importing images into Samurai Warriors 4

Tags: ps3, samurai-warriors-4

On Samurai Warriors 4 for PS3, there is an option to register images for created officers. The manual says you are able to use an image from your hard disk; however, that is *all* it says.

I have tried downloading custom images via the PS3 internet browser. But these images showed up too small for the bracket surrounding the image. I have no idea what resolution is expected in order for the custom image to fit properly.

What is the expected resolution for the images registered into Samurai Warriors 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from [GameFaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/800860-samurai-warriors-4/70364565):

> [The images] must be png or jpeg file[s] size limit 1024x1024

Thanks go to UltimaWeapon11 for this information, which he/she claims was taken from KOEI's website (somewhere.)